# Carrierwave resize is not working (Rails 3 and MiniMagick)

Tags: process, resize, carrierwave, minimagick

what I want to do is to save a website url with a full-size snapshot via IMGKit. In one of the views I also want to have a thumbnail version of the snapshot. I'm using carrierwave in order to associate the snapshot with the object an MiniMagick to manipulate it, the problem is that it generates the 'thumbnail' image but doesn't resize it so as a result, I have two full-size snapshots, one of then with 'thumb' as prefix.

I have this model in rails

```
class Webpage
  mount_uploader :snapshot, SnapshotUploader
  field :url, type: String
  field :title, type: String

  after_create :get_snapshot

  private
  def get_snapshot
    file = Tempfile.new(["#{id}#{title}".downcase, '.jpg'], 'tmp', :encoding => 'ascii-8bit')
    image = IMGKit.new(url, quality: 90).to_jpg
    file.write(image)
    file.flush
    self.snapshot= file
    self.save
    file.unlink
  end


end
```

And I have this in the Uploader in order to create the thumbnail version:

```
class SnapshotUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [180, 180]
  end

end
```

Using the console I tried MiniMagick for resizing an image and it works fine son I don't know what is happening.
I'm not sure if I'm doing it right so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

OK, I'm stupid. I had an initializer with

```
config.enable_processing = false
```

so it will never process the image. Just setting it to true or deleting the line solved my problem.